# Unable to Call Promise in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-promise

I am calling service in login class as per below:

**service.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers  } from "@angular/http";
import { apimodel } from '../../_model/APImodel';
import Global = require('../../_utilities/constants/constants');
import { UserModel } from '../../_model/usermodel';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';


export class services
{
    constructor(private http: Http){ }

    getLogin(model : UserModel)  {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post(Global.BASE_URL + '/login', model, options)
                .toPromise().then(res=><apimodel>res.json()).catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error:any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.log("Error");
        console.error(error); // log to console instead
        return Promise.reject(errMsg);
    }
}
```

and **login.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserModel } from '../../_model/usermodel';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import Global = require('../../_utilities/constants/constants');
import {apimodel} from "../../_model/APImodel";
import { services } from '../../_utilities/services/services';


@Component({
    templateUrl: './_componant/login/login.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{
    model : UserModel = {id : 0, email : "", password : "", username : ""};
    myform : FormGroup;
    submitted : boolean = false;
    returnUrl : string;
    response : apimodel;

    constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private services : services){

    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.myform = new FormGroup({
            username : new FormControl("", Validators.required),
            password : new FormControl("", Validators.required)
        })

        this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
    }

    login(model : UserModel){
        this.submitted = true;
        if(this.myform.valid)
        {
            this.services.getLogin(model).then(result => console.log(result)).catch(error => console.log(error));
            //Call Web Service to login
            console.log(this.returnUrl);
            this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        }
    };
}
```

**module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule ,appRouterModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, LoginComponent, RegistrationComponent],
  bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
  providers: [services]
})
```

Error:

> (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for services

If I remove provider from module.ts, I am getting following error.

> No provider for services

**Update**
I've added @Injectable() like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class services
{
```

But I am still getting error : http://prntscr.com/hz3e3a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing **`@Injectable()`**

```
@Injectable()
export class services{
```

Comment: I've added @Injectable() before class. But I am still getting error: No provider for Http! ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:

Comment: you need to add HttpModule to your app.ts

Comment: I think I've added in service.ts